# deactivated QListWidgetItem :hover

Tags: qt, hover, qlistwidget, qtstylesheets

I implemented a `QListWidget` and added this to prevent a highlight effect when I'm with the mouse over an item:

```
QListWidget::item:hover { background: transparent; }
```

But then I disabled some items with `lwi->setFlags(lwi->flags() & ~Qt::ItemIsEnabled);` (`lwi` ist the QListWidgetItem to disable) to prevent selection and now these are not affected by

```
QListWidget::item:hover.
```

How can I disable the highlight effect on all items (including the disabled)?

Answer (score 2):

You can try setting following styles, should work

```
QListWidget::item:hover,
QListWidget::item:disabled:hover,
QListWidget::item:hover:!active,
{background: transparent;}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just came across this issue. This seemed to do the trick:

```css
QListWidget::item:disabled
{
    background: transparent;
}
```